# Android preferences changed

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have some preferences in my activity and I would like to achieve that, depending on these preferences, some services will be initiated or not.
I am trying to implement and `onSharedPreferenceChanged`method, but it never gets called (even if I have assigned it to a field).
The code is the following:

```
public class MtprojectActivity extends Activity {
...
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
callsCheckbox = prefs.getBoolean("callsLogChk", true);
listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
                if (!started) { 
                    startCallsService();
                    bindCallsService();
                } else {
                    releaseCallsService();
                    stopCallsService();
                }
            }
        };

        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it isn't being called or is it just a case of it not doing what you expect? I may be wrong but shouldn't the code look like this...

```
if (key.equals("callsLogChk")) {
    if (!started) { // Check NOT started ???
        startCallsService();
        bindCallsService();
    }
    else { // The 'else' should compliment the check for !started ???
        releaseCallsService();
        stopCallsService();
    }
}
```

Sorry, as I don't know your code I may be totally wrong but as you've posted it, it doesn't look quite right to me.

**EDIT:**

Also, are you making sure you call the `SharedPreferences.Editor.commit()` method when you make the change to the preference?

Comment: yeah I changed it, but still the listener never gets called

Comment: no I don't do that, where should I do it, inside the onSharePreferenceChangedListener?

Comment: @noloman: Assuming you have a `CheckBox` which allows the user to toggle the setting, then you need to assign it an `onCheckedChangeListener` then edit the preference in that listener (and use `commit` obviously).

Comment: and that should be done in my main activity or in my PreferenceActivity?

Comment: @noloman: I've never used a `PreferenceActivity` and was assuming it was done elsewhere in the `Activity` you've posted (but you just hadn't included all code). I'm guessing you need to somehow have the `PreferenceActivity` update the default `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: well with my actual preferences, I never use `commit` or `edit` because the preferences are being stored automatically